# AC capacitor computational problem using calculus

Tags: capacitor, ac, power-electronics

[image: ac capacitor]

A current is flowing through an ideal capacitor, C = 25μF, the current waveform is a sawtooth. I need to find the formulas that plot the voltage waveform ,which is also shown in the figure,right below the current waveform. I need help to spot my mistakes in my computations when i apply the formulas.

$$\text{when}\,\, 0<t<1: i(t) = 5×10^6t\,\,\text{because slope}=\frac{5-0}{1×10^{-6}-0}=5×10^6$$

$$
\begin{align}
u(t) &= \frac{1}{C}\int_0^t i(t)dt\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{25×10^{-6}} \int_0^t\,5×10^6t \,dt\\ \\
&= \frac{5×10^6}{25×10^{-6}}\left.\frac{t^2}{2}\right\vert_0^t\\ \\
&= 0.1×10^{12}t^2\\
\end{align}
$$ Thus, between 0 < t < 1 i get a parabola pattern y = ax^2. I think that part is correct(judging from the volts waveform). Below comes the problematic part which i suspect i get it wrong and i need help please to find the correct solution.

$$\text{when}\,\, 1 < t < 2: i(t) = 5×10^6t\,\,\text{because slope}=\frac{0-(-5)}{(2-1)×10^{-6}}=5×10^6$$

$$
\begin{align}
u(t) &= \frac{1}{C}\int_0^t i(t)dt\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{25×10^{-6}} \int_{10^{-6}}^t\,5×10^6t \,dt \\ \\
&=\frac{5×10^6}{25×10^{-6}}\left.\frac{t^2}{2}\right\vert_{10^{-6}}^t\\ \\
&=\frac{5×10^6}{2×25×10^{-6}}\Bigr(t^2 -(10^{-6})^2\,\Bigl) 0.1×10^{12}\Bigr(t^2 -(10^{-6})^2\,\Bigl)\\ \\
&= 0.1×10^{12}t^2 -0.1
\end{align}
$$

BUT $$0.1×10^{12}t^2 -0.1 \,\,\, \text{is of the form } y=ax^2+b\, \, \text{I was expecting the pattern } \frac1x \text{ as the volts graph suggests when }1<t<2$$ 
I would like to ask for some help to find the correct solution.(this is an unsolved excercise from schaum's outline series electric circuits 2nd edition ex 1.42)

**EDIT:** test the formula u(t) for t = 1.5 x 10^(-6) seconds, when 1 < t < 2.  It outputs 0.125, invalid, because 0.125> 0.1. That's why i suspect there is probably a mistake.

Comment: The sawtooth is the same shape before and after the 'jump'. So why would you expect a different result? The only difference is the start voltage. Beware of your polarity!

Comment: the question is: I need to find the volts formula....I am given current waveform,it goes through a capacitor that current,the output waveform of volts is as shown, as a hint .I need to prove it using math formulas.

Comment: Why do you think the pattern should be 1/x???? The pattern is a parabola. For a regular parabola around the origin, there is a part which grows for x>0, and one that goes dows for x<0. The part you see for negative current is the part of the parabola that goes down.

Comment: @Claudio Avi Chami between 1<t<2 the volts pattern matches to 1/x(hyperbola). Parabola is bending outwards,but the volts curve is bent inwards when 1<t<2. Parabola is nowhere close the that inwards bending.

Comment: Here you have the simulation result https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/5269326500_1518275282.png

Comment: @G36 thanks. The simulation proves that the volts graph is as shown in my volts graph... I know the volts waveform, i failed to find the math formula. I suspect i made calculation mistakes i do not see between the time margin 1<t<2 :(

Answer (score 0):

\$Q = CV\$

Hence \$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$

Rearranging,  \$V = \dfrac{1}{C}\int i~ dt\$

If **i** is a ramp, it has the form **kt** where **k** is a constant and **t** is time.

So, \$V = \dfrac{k}{C}t^2\$

Voltage rise as a square of time then falls as a square of time etc..

Answer (score 0):

The integral of a +/- 5A sawtooth with initial conditions of 0A in and 0V out, results in a triangle which has 1/2 the area of a triangle.

I agree the waveform is a repeating parabola but the peak output voltage must be 1/2 of a square wave input of 5V for a triangle input.

### Alternative simplification

5A for a cycle of 2 us or a freq. of 500kHz with 1/2 the integral or 1 us

**Ic=C*dV/dt**  so for dV max from a triangle to be = 1/2 of square square wave,

re-arranged using a square step:
**max(dV)= ½ * Ic*dt/C** = ½ 5A * 1us /25uF = 0.1V
[image]

([Analog computers](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%207%206.25e-10%2010.20027730826997%2057%205%2050%0Ag%20104%20160%20104%20208%200%0Aw%20192%2080%20192%20112%200%0Aw%20192%20112%20192%20144%200%0Aa%20104%20144%20192%20144%200%2015%20-15%201000000%201.380277644181099e-7%200%0Ac%20128%2080%20192%2080%202%200.000024999999999999998%200.013802914469575411%0AO%20272%20144%20336%20144%200%0Av%2048%20160%2048%20128%200%204%20500000%205%200%203.141592653589793%200.5%0Aw%20312%20184%20344%20184%200%0Aw%20104%2080%20128%2080%200%0Ar%2048%20128%20104%20128%200%201%0Aa%20224%20176%20272%20176%202%2015%20-15%201000000%20-1.3802500391803157e-7%200%0Ar%20192%20144%20224%20144%200%201000%0Ar%20224%20144%20272%20144%200%201000%0Aw%20224%20168%20224%20144%200%0Aw%20272%20176%20272%20144%200%0Aw%20104%2080%20104%20128%200%0Aw%20104%20160%2048%20160%200%0Ag%20224%20184%20224%20192%200%0Ao%205%2032%200%204354%200.171875%200.00009765625%200%201%20integral%0Ao%209%2032%200%204353%2010%206.4%200%202%209%203%0Ao%204%2032%200%204097%201.25%206.4%201%202%204%203%0Ao%204%2032%200%2012546%200.10106248624154192%200.0001%201%202%204%203%0A) cannot drive 5A so this must be scaled to mA, but this simulator is near ideal.)

### p.s.

For input sawtooth waveform function.  consider   **for t in μs**

**i(t)= 5*(t - 2*INT(t/2+0.5))**   ( for integer rounding at >=0.5 = 1, <0.5 = 0 )

Comment: thanks. But i would like my math formula proof for u(t) to be edited(i think there is a mistake) so that it outputs correct values.For example, I just edited my question at the bottom and gave a test value: t = 1.5 and i got an impossible output.

Comment: wrong input formula for sawtooth

Comment: ok. 1)What's the correct formula using my diagram? 2) i do not understand the notation of your i(t) in bold letters.

Comment: my formula will work for any t>=0 ... I cleaned up the syntax around the INTeger function

Comment: sorry i do not understand your formula...Also i suppose that 'INT' means integer...Finally, in my case, i tried to construct a solution directly from the graph one piece at a time, 0 < t < 1 and one more piece: 1 < t < 2.

Comment: My formula is continuous sawtooth... you can replace t in excel with a column of times in increments of 0.1 or less using copy down + t incr. and use this formula to compute u(t) result.  Then use formula for integral for output and see the plot using XY (scatter) plot or use my Falstad simulator

Comment: i don't question the validity of your formula because i don't fully comprehend it. For time interval 0<t<1 what is your i(t)? And then for 1<t<2 what is your i(t)? i have provided one for both cases of i(t), i paced the solution one piece at a time, that's what i look for. I am looking for a math solution written down(solved by hand, not computers)

Comment: for t=0.1 , i(t)=5*(0.1- (2 * INT(0.1/2+0.5))=0.5A   for t=1 , i(t)= 5*(1-(2*INT(1/2+0.5))=5(1-2)= -5A  etc....   I just created a periodic function (t)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. When i say i don't understand i mean: Looking the  i(t) graph i provided in my question and ONLY that graph i can NOT arrive to your formula for the 2 aforementioned time intervals. y=at, a= slope, i calculated the slope and that's how got i(t). No matter how hard i try i can not make that y=at look like your formula :) i don't look at your circuit, i believe you that  it works.

Comment: Another way to look at it is y=a(t - int(t*f) for any t>=0 where  f=0.5  [MHz] and t in [us]  to the second part is a negative step staircase at f=1/T interval  but if it is easier for you to just use 2 intervals ok

Comment: i see the trickery now, but the problem-question(it's not mine!i just attempted to solve it) does not want you to use f.

Comment: so for latter ... and t=0.1, 0.5 1, 1.5,2,  i(2)= 5(2-int(2 * 0.5))=5, .... i(1.5)=5 ( 1.5 - int(1.5*0.5))=5 * (1.5-2) = -2.5A  This method becomes useful for continuous calculations using an input function